# Should I list my old blog in my current resume?

Tags: resume

I recently graduated as journalist and I have an old blog in which I used to upload articles, pictures and information of my own following the guidelines of my field, but I haven't updated it since january 2015. Should I include it in my resume today?

I've been reading similar questions around here but I think most of the people have them updated. What concerns me is that my employeer thinks I lack of interest in my field, but the truth is I havent had time for my own social networks. I would appreaciate your opinions. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

> Should I include it in my resume today?

If it's relevant to the kinds of jobs you are seeking, isn't too far out of date (such that it looks like you don't keep up with your field), isn't littered with a lot of personal posts that have nothing to do with your profession, and isn't lame, then you *could* include it.

You have a judgement call to make on whether you *should* include it or not.

Some folks choose to leave references to their website/blog off of their resume, but include it in a cover letter when they think it will be helpful. That's the route I have chosen in the past.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

People list their projects and or work that are relevant to the jobs they are applying for. If you think this blog represents talent that is relevant to your field then you should include it. If not, then it's probably not a good idea to list it as a project, however you could mention it as a hobby at a worst case scenario if you think it's not relevant enough. The date has nothing to do with it, however.

Most projects have a start date and an end date, there's nothing abnormal about you stop blogging, you may have other projects to think about or simply focus on your personal life outside of work. As long as what you've done is relevant to your field then you should include it.

If someone asks why you stopped working on your project you can simply state what you've already said, you've been busy.